# Different functions from different scripts in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I want to make a script which calls functions from different scripts, but once I've called another script, every single internal function doesn't recognize it.

I have no idea how to go on. I tried to erase the call, but once I erase the call to another script, obviously, these functions aren't working.

```
#!/bin/bash

. generalFunct
is_stora_mounted="true"
counter=0
user1000=$(cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd | egrep ':[0-9]{4}$' | cut -d: -f1)

doCheckSudo
doDisableCdrom
doCheckOS
doAddProgramSources
doInstallOtherDependency
doAddSources
doAddAnsibleSources
doInstallPrinter
doInstallSenior

doAddAnsibleSources() {
    bla bla bla bla
}



doInstallSenior() {

    bla bla bla bla bla bla

}
doInstallVPN
doUpgradeAndUpdate
doInstallWifiDriver
doAddCertificates
doDownloadDockerImages

[BLA BLA BLA IT'S TO KEEP THE PRIVACY ON MY WORKPLACE]
```

doAddAnsibleSources and doInstallSenior are the functions which are internal.

I expected to work, but it says that it can't find the order (refering to the function title)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "every single internal function doesn't recognize it"? What are internal functions versus external functions?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Barmar with "internal functions" I mean functions from the same script which is launching. "External functions" means functions from another script which are called from the script launched.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/KJ4uqqx.png

There's a screenshot with the error

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, take your current scripts, make copies, remove everything that isn't related to the problem (if you remove something and the problem vanishes, it *was* related, so put it back). When you've removed as much as possible and the problem still occurs, add *all* of the involved scripts to your question. That way, other people can see everything involved, and try it out themselves.

Comment: I edited the post to add the entire script (the main one)

Comment: Are you trying to call the functions before they're defined...?

Comment: @danlor Jesus, you deserve a beer buddy. I didn't saw that. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the functions are defined **after** they are called. Move them to the top of the script and try again.

```sh
doAddAnsibleSources() {
 ...
}

doAddAnsibleSources
```

Instead of:

```sh
doAddAnsibleSources

doAddAnsibleSources() {
 ...
}
```

This is required as bash is interpreted environment and does no preprocessing, just executes line after line. When reading a file in this way, it tries to execute function it hasn't seen yet.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qFLXl20.png

Comment: Yeah, it's true. Thanks <3